# How to send two messages in quick succession, received all at once

Tags: go, websocket, gorilla

I have two services running inside separate Docker containers and they send messages between each other using Gorilla Websocket. I am able to send messages fine one at a time but when I send two in quick succession they arrive on the receiver during a single read causing my unmarshalling to fail.

On the sender side I have a loop that sends two messages:

```
for _, result := range results {
    greetingMsg := Message{
        TopicIdentifier: *bot.TopicIdentifier,
        UserIdentifier:  botIdentifier,
        Message:         result,
    }

    msgBytes, err := json.Marshal(greetingMsg)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Sender failed marshalling greeting message with error " + err.Error())
    }

    log.Printf("Sender writing %d bytes of message\n%s\n", len(msgBytes), string(msgBytes))
    err = conn.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, msgBytes)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Sender failed to send message\n%s\nwith error %s ", string(msgBytes), err.Error())
    }
}
```

As expected I get two logs from just before conn.WriteMessage() call:

```
2019/12/12 06:23:29 agent.go:119: Sender writing 142 bytes of message
{"topicIdentifier":"7f7d12ea-cee8-4f05-943c-2e802638f075","userIdentifier":"753bcb8a-d378-422e-8a09-a2528565125d","message":"I am doing good"}

2019/12/12 06:23:29 agent.go:119: Sender writing 139 bytes of message
{"topicIdentifier":"7f7d12ea-cee8-4f05-943c-2e802638f075","userIdentifier":"753bcb8a-d378-422e-8a09-a2528565125d","message":"How are you?"}
```

On the receiver side I am listening as follows:

```
_, msg, err := conn.ReadMessage()
fmt.Printf("Receiver received %d bytes of message %s\n", len(msg), string(msg))
```

And that log messages produces:

```
2019/12/12 06:23:29 Receiver received 282 bytes of message  {"topicIdentifier":"83892f58b4b0-4303-8973-4896eed67ce0","userIdentifier":"119ba709-77a3-4b34-92f0-2187ecab7fc5","message":"I am doing good"}
{"topicIdentifier":"83892f58-b4b0-4303-8973-4896eed67ce0","userIdentifier":"119ba709-77a3-4b34-92f0-2187ecab7fc5","message":"How are you?"}
```

So for the two conn.WriteMessage() calls on the sender I get one message on the conn.ReadMessage() call on the receiver with all the data.

I think there is some kind of race condition here since sometimes the receiver does get two separate messages as expected but that is a rare occurrence.

Is there something fundamental that I'm missing here or do I simply need to make an extra call on the sender/receiver to only process one message at once?

Comment: Run the application with the race detector.

Comment: i tried simulating the same.. but it's working fine for me.. could you post your go version and also the gorilla/WebSocket branch/commit?

Comment: Go Version:  go1.13.5 linux/amd64 and in my go.mod Gorilla is specified as github.com/gorilla/websocket v1.4.0 which appears to be commit 66b9c49e59c6c48f0ffce28c2d8b8a5678502c6d. I'm also using FROM golang:alpine as my base image for all my containers.

Comment: see ReadJSON() in gorilla api.

Comment: This could indeed be a race condition if two or more go routines are writing on the same connection. Is this the case ? Writing a message is a three step process. Open the message, write the message data, close the message. If two writes occur before the close, the two data will be concatenated in the same message.

Answer (score 0):

If the messages are buffered, it is normal that both messages are received at once. The problem is on the receiving end that assumes that one read returns one messages.

As you have seen, a read may return more than one message. And also, a message may be split over multiple reads. The later depends on the message size. Only you know what a message is, and how it is delimited.

You have to implement a function that returns the next message. Here is a suggested implementation assuming that the state of message reading is stored in a struct.

```golang
type MessageParser struct {
    buf []byte
    nBytes int
    conn ... 
}

func NewMessageParser(conn ...) *MessageParser {
    return &MessageParser{
        buf: make([]byte, 256) // best gess of longest message size
        conn: conn
    }
}

func (m *MessageParser) NextMessage() (string, error) {
    var nOpenBrakets, pos int
    var inString bool
    for {
        // scan m.buf to locate next message
        for pos < m.nBytes {
            if m.buf[pos] == '{' && !inString {
                nOpenBrakets++
            } else if m.buf[pos] == '}' && !inString {
                nOpenBrakets--
                if nOpenBrakets == 0 {
                    // we found a full message
                    msg := string(m.buf[:pos+1])
                    m.nBytes = copy(buf, buf[pos+1:m.nBytes)
                    return msg, nil
                }
            } else if m.buf[pos] == '"' {
                if !inString {
                    inString = true
                } else if pos > 0 && m.buf[pos-1] != '\\' {
                    inString = false
                }
            }
            pos++
        }
        // if a message is longer than the buffer capacity, grow the buffer
        if m.nBytes == len(m.buf) {
            temp := make([]byte, len(m.buf)*2)
            copy(temp, m.buf)
            m.buf = temp
        }
        // we didn’t find a full message, read more data
        n, err := conn.Read(m.buf[m.nBytes:]
        m.nBytes += n
        if n == 0 && err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look into gorilla WebSockets code for the write function

```
NextWriter returns a writer for the next message to send. The writer's Close
// method flushes the complete message to the network.
```

the reader also has the same implementation.it seems to be proper.
Maybe as @chmike suggested the messages might have gotten buffered.

As for implementation, you could always add a delimiter to the end of the message and while reading parse the message till the delimiter is reached(in case the message overflows)

```
func writeString(conn *websocket.Conn, data []byte) {
conn.WriteMessage(1, append(data, "\r\n"...))
}
```

I tried to reproduce the same but it's just not working for me. at a low level, the connection api are generally compiled using c files. you could try building your application using "-tags netgo" to build it purely using go.